# Samba/CIFS to Synology NAS not working: no write access after upgrade from 16.04 to 20.04

Tags: permissions, mount, samba, cifs

Just took the plunge and upgraded from 16.04 to 20.04 and has a bunch of issues getting my NAS drive to mount at all (fixed by changing the sex from ntml to ntmlssp) and I can access it now but only have read permissions.

It's a synology NAS and the user I'm logging in as has read/write permissions to the share which were working previously in 16.04 and have tested on a windows machine and mac.

I'm fairly basic with my linux knowledge so let me know if you need anything else. Current fstab is

//192.168.1.228/Media /media/windowsshare cifs username=myusername,password=mypassword,vers=3.0,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntmlssp 0 0

As previously stated this was working in 16.04 and since then the only change I made was to change the sec from ntml to ntmlssp.

Comment: 16.04 > 20.04 is not a supported upgrade path.  See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> //192.168.1.228/Media /media/windowsshare cifs
> username=myusername,password=mypassword,vers=3.0,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntmlssp
> 0 0

I betcha it is writeable but not to you only to root. You need to take possession of the mounted share in Ubuntu by adding uid=myusername to the list of options:

```
//192.168.1.228/Media /media/windowsshare cifs username=myusername,password=mypassword,uid=myusername,vers=3.0,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntmlssp 0 0
```

Comment: You are 100% correct! Thank you so much, I can stop banging my head against the wall now! Now to go off and learn more about uid to avoid similar mistakes in future...