# Can't access Synology NAS from UBUNTU 18.04 (samba related??)

Tags: 18.04, samba, nas, smb

new to NAS also not an expert by any mean in Ubuntu, i've setup my Synology DS420+ yesterday and slowly modifying settings. I can access it using my one Windows 10 desktop but not another. I enabled WS-Discovery in NAS and the other win 10 machine works too. Side question, since it wasn’t' enable by default for security reasons, did i make my NAS much more vulnerable? I couldn’t access it from the laptop otherwise.

Main question, I have Ubuntu 18.04LTS and I can see the NAS but when I click on it I get an error message that’s it’s not accessible? Do I need to enable any other settings? In the NAS have the firewall enabled without changing any settings in it. I also have the default SMB options enabled.

I do remember changing something from samba?? few years back to access old router connected USB drive. Could this be SAMBA related? I edited a file before but forgot what's it called.

Thanks

Comment: Strange.  Could you open the file manager and click on 'Other locations' (not sure of the english name).  There, you have 'Connect to server' and a box where you can type the address in the form `smb://192.168.2.176/` where the number after smb is the IP adress of your NAS.  At that point, the system should ask you for a uid / password.

Comment: I believe Synology NAS'es have solid NFS support. As far as I know, Samba is Windows-oriented. NFS is more likely in a Linux environment. It might be that it's not enabled by default... If you can connect on Windows, then visit the Synology admin interface through the browser, and in the settings look for the NFS interface, and enable it. Also look into what else can be configured. Possibly you need to add your laptop's LAN IP address in somewhere, as an IP allowed to connect. Also look up a Linux-oriented Synology howto article on the Synology website and/or elsewhere on the net.

Comment: Marc - I can't do that.. It doesn't even let me press enter for my NAS address. My NAS address is static to.

Comment: Levente - I am not very knowledgeable in networking but from what I've head NFS isn't secure. It doesn't require password. I don't want a compromised device on my network to access the password less share folder. I didn't enable NFS on my NAS for that reason. Andadter  I do have another Ubuntu which is 20.04 Lts and that one, although it gives me the same error the first time, second click pop out the login info for the Nas so that one is good. It's the 18.04 laptop that's the problem. I had messed aground with samba in that machine before so not sure if that's causing the issue

Comment: HELP: I upgraded the 18.04 to 20.04 & still the same issue (I see the Nas name twice by the way and it has "(File Sharing)" written beside the name in both times). When I click on it I still get error "Unable to access location" and below that header it says "Failed to retrieve share list from server: Invalid argument". Now just to double check my other laptop that already had ubuntu 20.04 in it which I tested before and it worked once, now it's giving me the same error as the other laptop. It's not the network it's on since it has dual boot and I booted up win 10 and was able to access NAS.

Comment: Still need help but temporarily solved the issue : I had to enable min SMB to 1 from 2 in NAS. This was after I already edited SMB.conf file to have both client and sever minimum to SMB2. 

I don't know much about SMB but what I've read is that SMB 1 isn't very secure, even my NAS noted it. Anyway to get Ubuntu to work when NAS minimum is SMB2? Appreciate the help

Comment: This is just a stab in the dark, but is it possible to talk to the synology via `cifs`? I have no experience with it, but cifs seems native to linux and it speaks Samba 3. The desired password protection is also there... See this thread https://askubuntu.com/questions/1287681/samba-cifs-to-synology-nas-not-working-no-write-access-after-upgrade-from-16-04 and this https://askubuntu.com/questions/101029/how-do-i-mount-a-cifs-share and here's a doc: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/mount.cifs.8.html

Comment: I don't see a separate cifs.. I see nfs, smh, afs (apple one). There are bunch of advanced options in Synology under SMB but don't see cifs

Comment: I would imagine it works such way that the NAS continues to share via Samba, in other words the "Windows-oriented filesharing". On Ubuntu however the cifs package is doing the communication, via SMB protocol... From the NAS it could still seem as if a Windows machine were on the other end of the wire. That's why the NAS shouldn't need an option for cifs. Again, I just assume it could work this way, I never tried. But these people managed to do it (same link as above): https://askubuntu.com/questions/1287681/samba-cifs-to-synology-nas-not-working-no-write-access-after-upgrade-from-16-04

Comment: Found this today: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1050460/how-to-mount-smb-share-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Comment: Ok on my NAS it shows connection for that ubuntu is CIFS... so why is it not connecting if I change samba setting?